# Escape `#` in a command when opening a url

Tags: vim

I am trying to open the following url:

```
:execute 'silent !open https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#environment-variables'
```

However, it seems like when I run this command, the `#` is replaced (again) with the filepath instead of appearing as `#` literally. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`escape()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#escape()):

```
:execute 'silent !open' escape('https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#environment-variables', '#')
```

Comment: cool, here is what I did: `:execute 'silent !open' escape(expand('<cfile>'), '#')`

Answer (score 3):

Escape it with a backslash:

```
:execute 'silent !open https://github.com/junegunn/fzf\#environment-variables'
```

Comment: how would I do that in a function then? For example, I don't have control of the entered url? Something like:  `:execute substitute('silent !open <C-R><C-F>', '#', '\\#')`

Comment: `:execute 'silent !open' fnameescape(expand("<cWORD>"))` or something I guess? Please try to make sure to include all relevant details in the question so that the answers you get will be useful to you.

Comment: yes I think doing `fnameescape` is the best option here. I just changed it from `cWORD` to `afile` and it's all good now.